# Relationship between Lebesgue–Stieltjes measure and regular Borel measure

Tags: measure-theory, stieltjes-integral

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration:

> The Lebesgue–Stieltjes measure is a regular Borel measure, and conversely every regular Borel measure on the real line is of this kind.

As far as I know, a Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure is a regular Borel measure. But I can't find any proof for the reversed side. Could anyone help me?

Comment: What about $\mu(\emptyset) := 0$, $\mu(A) := \infty$ for all $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\, A \neq \emptyset$?

Comment: @Thomas: your measure is not regular

Comment: Why not? If $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is measurable, then either $A=\emptyset$, so it is already compact and open, or it contains a point $x$, then $\{x\} \subseteq A$ is compact and $\mu(\{x\}) = \infty = \mu(A)$, and any open superset $O$ of $A$ satisfies $\mu(O) = \infty = \mu(A)$.

Comment: @Thomas: I think that a regular Borel measure on the real line is outer regular and finite for every compact set (according to Folland's book, page 99). The definition of regular measure in [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_measure) is not this kind of measure, as your example. Thank you for your simple but elegant example.

Comment: After re-reading Folland's book, I find the answer is exactly Theorem 1.16 of the book which mentions that a measure on $\mathbb{R}$ that is finite on all bounded Borel sets is a Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure (after completion). As Thomas mentioned, the statement in this question is not true when using the definition of a regular Borel measure on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_Borel_measure).